# Flutter intl_phone_number_input - getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber giving error

Tags: flutter, dart, package, typeerror, phone-number

I am trying the getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber function from the intl_phone_number_input Flutter Package (0.7.1 - latest one)

It was functioning before but I was testing it today and it gave this error:

```
//CODE FROM THEIR PACKAGE
String phoneNumber =  '+234 500 500 5005';
PhoneNumber number = await PhoneNumber.getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

//ERROR
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PhoneNumberUtil')
 at getRegionInfo (http://localhost:51866/packages/libphonenumber_web/src/libphonenumber_plugin.dart.lib.js:56:58)
    at getRegionInfo.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at libphonenumber_plugin.LibPhoneNumberPlugin.new.getRegionInfo (http://localhost:51866/packages/libphonenumber_web/src/libphonenumber_plugin.dart.lib.js:55:20)
    at getRegionInfo (http://localhost:51866/packages/libphonenumber_plugin/src/phone_number_util.dart.lib.js:49:75)
    at getRegionInfo.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at PhoneNumberUtil.getRegionInfo (http://localhost:51866/packages/libphonenumber_plugin/src/phone_number_util.dart.lib.js:48:20)
    at getRegionInfo (http://localhost:51866/packages/intl_phone_number_input/src/utils/phone_number/phone_number_util.dart.lib.js:158:65)
    at getRegionInfo.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at PhoneNumberUtil.getRegionInfo (http://localhost:51866/packages/intl_phone_number_input/src/utils/phone_number/phone_number_util.dart.lib.js:157:20)
    at getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber (http://localhost:51866/packages/intl_phone_number_input/src/utils/phone_number/phone_number_util.dart.lib.js:476:68)
    at getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at PhoneNumber.getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber (http://localhost:51866/packages/intl_phone_number_input/src/utils/phone_number/phone_number_util.dart.lib.js:474:20)
    at upload_data_form._UploadDataFormState.new.<anonymous> (http://localhost:51866/packages/excelit/widgets/remember_me.dart.lib.js:13587:84)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at http://localhost:51866/packages/excelit/widgets/remember_me.dart.lib.js:13531:218
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40511:59)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:35438:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:35999:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:36037:17)
    at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:35872:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:35906:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:51866/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

I tried on several valid phone numbers
My code reads an Excel File row by row and creates a Client Object (name, address... phone_num)

[image]

```
//TEMPLIST: [Client A, Mr. Ahmad, ahmad@mindit.com, Lebanon, Beirut, Badaro, 96181816583, -, -]
//phonenumber returned by the string manipulation below is +96181816583 which should be valid

 PhoneNumber number1 = await PhoneNumber
                                            .getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber((tempList
                                                        .elementAt(6)
                                                        .substring(0, 1) !=
                                                    '+')
                                                ? '+${tempList.elementAt(6).replaceAll(' ', '')}'
                                                : tempList
                                                    .elementAt(6)
                                                    .replaceAll(' ', ''),)
                                        .onError((error, stackTrace) {
                                      failureSnackBar(context,
                                          'Invalid or missing phone_num in ${file.name} row ${row.elementAt(0)!.rowIndex + 1}');
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                      breakLoop = true;
                                      return PhoneNumber();
                                    });
```

This same Excel file worked before and I could get the PhoneNumbers right but now it isn't.
And even if i specify the isoCode it still gives the same error.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer this but I forgot to add these in the index.html

```
<script src="assets/packages/libphonenumber_plugin/js/libphonenumber.js"></script>
<script src="assets/packages/libphonenumber_plugin/js/stringbuffer.js"></script>
```